# Cannot show html value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried to use javascript to alert the selected textarea value. I am using `$("#kandungan_email").html();` to get the whole HTML value include `&#13;&#10;`, but it cannot get `&#13;&#10;`

Below is my code:

```js
function hantar_terpilih(){
var content = $("#kandungan_email").html();
alert(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" rows="9" class="form-control" id="kandungan_email" name="kandungan_email" value="" title="Kandungan Email">Title:TEST&#13;&#10;Time:12PM&#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&#13;&#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&#13;&#10;Lampiran : http://google.com &#13;&#10;Thanks.</textarea>

<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="hantar_terpilih()">Hantar yang terpilih</button>
```

The result is shown like below:

[image: output]

Actually, I want the result to be shown like below, just show all HTML value:

```html
Title:TEST&#13;&#10;Time:12PM&#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&#13;&#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&#13;&#10;Lampiran : http://google.com &#13;&#10;Thanks.
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Note: Don't effect shown in the textarea value.

Comment: `textarea` is a form control so use `val()`, not `html()`

Comment: I have tried used val(), the result is still the same.

Comment: you need to change &to &amp;. Then in alert it will show.

Comment: @AmitVerma If change &to &amp;. it will also show in the textarea.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353129/jquery-escaping-html-from-a-textarea

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the content is parsed by the browser you won't be able to access the HTML entities (&#13; and &#10;). If you can store the content in a JavaScript string, you can display it's original form in the alert.

```js
function hantar_terpilih(){
    var content = 'Title:TEST&#13;&#10;Time:12PM&#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&#13;&#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&#13;&#10;Lampiran : http://google.com &#13;&#10;Thanks.';
    alert(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" rows="9" class="form-control" id="kandungan_email" name="kandungan_email" title="Kandungan Email">Title:TEST&#13;&#10;Time:12PM&#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&#13;&#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&#13;&#10;Lampiran : http://google.com &#13;&#10;Thanks.</textarea>
<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="hantar_terpilih()">Hantar yang terpilih</button>
```

If you have many textareas with different contents you will need to choose a strategy to relate the textearea / button to the corresponding javascript variable holding the string.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've used is to apply `JSON.stringify` on the primitive `string`. Then I'd replaced `\r` and `\n` with their ASCII code. Finally, I've removed the quotes around the value.

```js
function hantar_terpilih() {
  var content = JSON.stringify($("#kandungan_email").html());
  content = content.replace(/\\r/g, `&#13;`);
  content = content.replace(/\\n/g, `&#10;`);
  if (content.charAt(0) === '"' && content.charAt(content.length - 1) === '"') {
    content = content.substr(1, content.length - 2);
  }
  alert(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" rows="9" class="form-control" id="kandungan_email" name="kandungan_email" value="" title="Kandungan Email">Title:TEST&#13;&#10;Time:12PM&#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&#13;&#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&#13;&#10;Lampiran : http://google.com &#13;&#10;Thanks.</textarea>

<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="hantar_terpilih()">Hantar yang terpilih</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` is an **escapable raw text element** [see here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2:escapable-raw-text-elements-3)

any characters or letters after the "&" and that ends with ";" (semicolon) gets parsed as a character reference. (eg. **(&)nbsp;**)

so used `&amp#13;` instead of `&#13;`

```js
function hantar_terpilih(){
var content = $("#kandungan_email").html();
alert(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" rows="9" class="form-control" id="kandungan_email" name="kandungan_email" value="" title="Kandungan Email">Title:TEST&amp#13;&amp#10;Time:12PM&amp#13;&#10;Place:Guangzhao&amp#13;&amp#10;Please login to http://google.com for more details&amp#13;&amp#10;Lampiran : http://google.com #13;&amp#10;Thanks.&amp#13;&amp#10;</textarea>

<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="hantar_terpilih()">Hantar yang terpilih</button>
```

Comment: Can don't effect show in the textarea value. Because textarea show `&#13;&#10;`